# django query get rows where two columns difference is greater than a value

Tags: django-models

I have a table in my model including some feature and I want to execute select query like this in Django:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE column1-column2 > 10000
```

I tried `filter()`, but after a little search I found out that I should use `.annotate()` and I changed my query to:

```
Account.objects.annotate(realcharge=(F('charge')-F('amount')), realcharge__lt=10000)
```

But i get this error:

```
'int' object has no attribute 'resolve_expression'
```

How should I write my query?
my django version is 1.11.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if you still need an answer, but you could try the `.filter()` method after the call to `.annotate()`, like this:

```
# Note: I split this query in 2 lines for better readability

qs = Account.objects.annotate(realcharge=(F('charge')-F('amount')))
qs = qs.filter(realcharge__lt=10000)
```